# Complex mappings with ORM

Tags: entity-framework, nhibernate, orm, ef-code-first

I have used Entity Framework Code First once and although it is easy to deal with i feel like it forces you to fight your OOP principles as i tend to break many habits and design decisions just so Code First can understand my entities and map/read them from the db like:

- You can't use ReadOnlyCollections
- You can't have a collection of a Complex Type (Value Type)
- Forced to use a hack to make enumerations work, (most market customers still have Windows XP)

and I can name a few more. What i would like to know if NHibernate supports the stuff mentioned above on Windows XP plus other things (like if it can work with SQL CE) and things that doesn't force you to change your design just to make it work.
I would like to hear an NHibernate professional/expert on this ?

Comment: I can't help you with the question sorry (I am interested in the answer) but I can't believe the vote down without a comment. Some people are just full of self importance.

Comment: I suspect the vote down is because of the title. The title doesn't allow for a single answer and opens the door for a debate.

Comment: @Rippo, i agree but the content of the question does not, and on the other side i don't think the new edited title isn't debatable.

Comment: Much better, some people are lazy in nature and can't be bothered to read the content, they judge by the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about ReadOnlyCollections in particular, as NHibernate requires using interfaces and then uses its own collection implementation (which you can replace). But you can always map a private field and use a projection.

The others work out of the box.